# Default values in list query parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I am trying to display default values in Swashbuckle. Is there a way to define default values in a query list parameter in a .NET Core API.
Something like:

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public ActionResult<string> TestFunc([FromQuery, BindRequired] List<string> testList = ["value1", "value2"]) {
//Do some stuff
           return Ok(results);

}
```

Comment: Any update? Does my reply help you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @BrandoZhang , I will try this today and let you know!

Comment: I have updated the my answer. Does it help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, we couldn't set the default parameter value must be compile-time constant which means we couldn't set a default value for a list or array of string.

That means there is no way to set the defualt value inside the web api paramter.

If you want to show the default value inside the swagger. You could create a class which inherit from IOperationFilter.

Then you could check the paramter name, if the name is equals the testList ,you could set the custom description.

More details, you could refer to below codes example:

Custom class:

```
public class ParameterClass : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var parameter in operation.Parameters) {

            if (parameter.Name == "testList")
            {
                parameter.Description = @"Default value: ['value1', 'value2']";
            }
        }

 
    }
}
```

Register the swaggergen with filter :

```
      services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
        
c.OperationFilter<ParameterClass>();
        });
```

Result:

[image]

---

Update:

If you want to set the parameter like query string, you could modify the apply method as below:

```
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
        {
            return;
        }


        foreach (var parameter in operation.Parameters) {

            if (parameter.Name == "testList")
            {
                parameter.In = 0;
                 parameter.Description = @"['value1', 'value2']";
               
                parameter.Schema = new OpenApiSchema() { Type = "string" ,Items = null };
                 
            }
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @BrandoZhang do you know if it is possible to fill out the values in the item fields of the list. So when I press "try it out" I want to see the values already filled out in the parameter list for the default items, making it easier for the user to remove items that he does't want to use.